# PyCrypto examples for Python3

Tags: python

I am looking for examples PyCrypto AES and RSA algorithms. Anybody can help me links, or examples right here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in the math for making RSA key pairs and applying them, here is a recipe that might interest you:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577737

For a complete implementation, why not look at the [source for PyCrypto](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto).